# Running C — helloWorld runs but nothing else — Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, runtime

I am just picking up the C language (strong with Java and Python).

When writing a C program such as hello world I compile it on the ubuntu cmd line with   gcc hello.c -o hello     from there I run it through ./hello    This works great.

Problem:

When writing a file that does any sort of "work"  (example files copied directly from the ANSI C book) the program complies perfectly but then just hangs....

Does anyone have any suggestion for why this might be happening?

Thank you very much!

Edit~~

Working code that compiles and runs:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    main()
    {
    printf("Hello,World\n");
    }
```

Code that compiles but hangs at run time:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    main()
    {
    int c, i , nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit [10];

    nwhite = nother =0;
    for (i =0; i < 10; ++i)
        ndigit[i] = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
          ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
          ++nwhite;
        else 
          ++nother;

    printf("digits = ");
    for (i =0; i< 10; ++i )
       printf("  %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf(", white psace = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);
    }
```

^^This is copied out of the Arrays section of the ANSI C book (Arrays section)

thanks

Comment: I imagine it's a problem with your code...

Comment: Indeed, we'd need to see WAAAY more to even begin to diagnose this. There are so many things that can go wrong with C it's not even funny. It could be something as simple as you're stuck in a ``while`` loop that isn't terminating, or it could be something much more complicated.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response.  I doubt the code has an issue since it is directly copied from the book written by D. Ritchie

Comment: The program is pausing waiting for user input. There is no default 'prompt' in C, it will just wait for you to do something with a blinking cursor. It happens here: ``while(c = getchar()) != EOF)``. It looks like it wants you to enter text, and then counts the number of alpha-numeric characters and whitespace. It only processes on a newline though.

Comment: P.S. ``c-'0'`` is a nifty shortcut to convert a (ASCII/utf8) numeric character to an ``int`` between ``0`` and ``9``.

Comment: When it "hangs", type some text and then press `CTRL-D` to tell it you're done entering text and it will "un-hang".

Comment: try `./prog < prog.c` or `./prog < hello.c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this will run until EOF is detected. 
EOF can be 'inserted' pressing ctrl+D in Linux terminal. 
It works OK then.

change `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` to `while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')` and it will only ask you for one line of input and then return the result.

btw: `main` is of type `int` and should return a value.